# Using LIKE to search for a name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which contains contact information. This table has 1 column relevant to names. It looks like this:

```
Sort Name:
Doe, John
Clinton, Bill
Dooby Doo, Scooby
```

Sadly, there are no first name / last name columns, and they can't be added.
If a user enters the search term "john doe", is there any way I can get mysql to return the column for "Doe, John" as my result?

Edit: As a follow up to the answer by RHSeeger, what would I do to make

```
john doe
```

into

```
$name(0=>'john', 1=>'doe')
```

using php

Thanks for the help so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thought would be:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE LOWER(sort_name) LIKE '%name1%'
  ...
  AND LOWER(sort_name) LIKE '%nameN%'
```

where <name1> ... <nameN> are the individual, lowercased "words" (split on space, comma?) in the name the user requested.

Edit: It's worth noting that, for a reasonably large sized data set, searches like this are going to be slow. If you're going to have lots of data, you could consider a search engine (like [SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)) that you use to search for things, and using MySQL just for lookup by ID.

Comment: And what would I do to take john doe into $name(0=>'john', 1=>'doe')

Comment: I can't answer the question in your comment, as I don't know PHP well at all. I was only addressing the MySQL component.

Comment: explode(" ", "john doe"); would yield an array (0 => "john", 1 => "doe")

Answer (score 0):

In your application, split the search term at the last space, change the order and add a comma in between.

Comment: That would fail if the user input "scooby dooby" but left out the doo

Answer (score 0):

I would begin by parsing the search into separable words "john" and "doe" then then write a search using the LIKE functionality for both terms.

EDIT:
To answer your question from a answer below... how do parse "John Doe" into "John" and "Doe"
I would write a MySQL stored procedure to separate them into a result set containing "John" and "Doe" and then use the like versus that column name

Answer (score 0):

Look in to the sql "like" operator. For example

```
select * from TABLENAME
where sort_name like '%doe'
```

You would need to do a little manipulation to the search terms on the application side and possibly supply other conditional clauses in your sql statement with other like clauses.

Answer (score 0):

have a full-text index on the names column and then do this,

```
select * from names where match(name) against ('john doe');
```